Group Data into sets by date intervals in oracle
I have data like the one below and am looking to get it grouped based on the time intervals where it is repeating for col1+col2 with start and end dates. Can anyone provide some tips to get the result in Oracle?
Col1 Col2   Date_col    Quantity
I1   L1     1-Jul-24    10
I1   L1     2-Jul-24    10
I1   L1     3-Jul-24    10
---------------------------------
I1   L1     12-Jul-24   10
I1   L1     13-Jul-24   10
I1   L1     14-Jul-24   10
---------------------------------
I2   L2     5-Jul-24    26
I2   L2     6-Jul-24    26
I2   L2     7-Jul-24    26
I2   L2     8-Jul-24    26
---------------------------------
I2   L2     10-Jul-24   34
I2   L2     11-Jul-24   34
---------------------------------
I2   L2     12-Jul-24   28
I2   L2     13-Jul-24   28
I2   L2     14-Jul-24   28
---------------------------------
I2   L2     21-Jul-24   20
I2   L2     22-Jul-24   20
I2   L2     23-Jul-24   20
I2   L2     24-Jul-24   20



Need to aggregate data grouped by col1 and col2 and get the data with start and end dates as the first and last dates of the pattern.
Desired Output
Col1   Col2   Startdate      Enddate      Quantity
I1     L1     1/Jul/2024     3/Jul/2024   10
I1     L1     12/Jul/2024    14/Jul/2024  10
I2     L2     5/Jul/2024     8/Jul/2024   26
I2     L2     10/Jul/2024    11/Jul/2024  34
I2     L2     12/Jul/2024    14/Jul/2024  28
I2     L2     21/Jul/2024    24/Jul/2024  20

Below are the DDLs to create the above data.
Create table tab1 as 
select 'I1' col1,'L1' col2,to_date('01-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY') Date_col,10 quantity from dual 
union
select 'I1','L1',to_date('02-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),10 from dual 
union
select 'I1','L1',to_date('03-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),10 from dual 
union
select 'I1','L1',to_date('12-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),10 from dual 
union
select 'I1','L1',to_date('13-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),10 from dual 
union
select 'I1','L1',to_date('14-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),10 from dual 
union
select 'I2','L2',to_date('05-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),26 from dual 
union
select 'I2','L2',to_date('06-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),26 from dual 
union
select 'I2','L2',to_date('07-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),26 from dual 
union
select 'I2','L2',to_date('08-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),26 from dual 
union
select 'I2','L2',to_date('10-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),34 from dual 
union
select 'I2','L2',to_date('11-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),34 from dual 
union
select 'I2','L2',to_date('12-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),28 from dual 
union
select 'I2','L2',to_date('13-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),28 from dual 
union
select 'I2','L2',to_date('14-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),28 from dual 
union
select 'I2','L2',to_date('21-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),20 from dual 
union
select 'I2','L2',to_date('22-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),20 from dual 
union
select 'I2','L2',to_date('23-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),20 from dual 
union
select 'I2','L2',to_date('24-07-2024','DD-MM-YYYY'),20 from dual;


Is col1, col2, date_col unique? Or can you get multiple rows with the same col1, col2, date_col and different quantities? If it is unique then solutions that include quantity in the PARTITION BY clauses will probably work; if it is not unique then you probably need to make that clear in the question (and I think the solutions that PARTITION BY col1, col2, quantity could output overlapping groups for that edge case). fiddle

From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE to perform row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT *
FROM   tab1
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY col1, col2
         ORDER BY date_col
         MEASURES
           FIRST(quantity) AS quantity,
           FIRST(date_col) AS start_date,
           LAST(date_col) AS end_date
         PATTERN (first_row consecutive*)
         DEFINE
           consecutive AS  quantity = FIRST(quantity)
                       AND date_col <= PREV(date_col) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
       )

Note: You (probably) do not want to include quantity in the columns you are partitioning by and, instead, check for identical quantities in the pattern matching.
Which, for the sample data:
Create table tab1 (col1, col2, date_col, quantity) as 
SELECT 'I1','L1',DATE '2024-07-01',10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I1','L1',DATE '2024-07-02',10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I1','L1',DATE '2024-07-03',10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I1','L1',DATE '2024-07-12',10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I1','L1',DATE '2024-07-13',10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I1','L1',DATE '2024-07-14',10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I2','L2',DATE '2024-07-05',26 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I2','L2',DATE '2024-07-06',26 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I2','L2',DATE '2024-07-07',26 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I2','L2',DATE '2024-07-08',26 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I2','L2',DATE '2024-07-10',34 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I2','L2',DATE '2024-07-11',34 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I2','L2',DATE '2024-07-12',28 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I2','L2',DATE '2024-07-13',28 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I2','L2',DATE '2024-07-14',28 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I2','L2',DATE '2024-07-21',20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I2','L2',DATE '2024-07-22',20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I2','L2',DATE '2024-07-23',20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'I2','L2',DATE '2024-07-24',20 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



COL1
COL2
QUANTITY
START_DATE
END_DATE




I1
L1
10
2024-07-01 00:00:00
2024-07-03 00:00:00


I1
L1
10
2024-07-12 00:00:00
2024-07-14 00:00:00


I2
L2
26
2024-07-05 00:00:00
2024-07-08 00:00:00


I2
L2
34
2024-07-10 00:00:00
2024-07-11 00:00:00


I2
L2
28
2024-07-12 00:00:00
2024-07-14 00:00:00


I2
L2
20
2024-07-21 00:00:00
2024-07-24 00:00:00



fiddle

In earlier versions you can use:
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       MIN(date_col) AS start_date,
       MAX(date_col) AS end_date,
       MAX(quantity) AS quantity
FROM   (
  SELECT col1,
         col2,
         date_col,
         quantity,
         SUM(has_changed_group) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY date_col)
           AS grp
  FROM   (
    SELECT col1,
           col2,
           date_col,
           quantity,
           CASE
           WHEN quantity = LAG(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY date_col)
           AND  date_col <= LAG(date_col) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY date_col)
                            + INTERVAL '1' DAY
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
           END AS has_changed_group
    FROM   tab1 t
  )
)
GROUP BY col1, col2, grp

fiddle

This is a gaps and island problem.  We can generate a new pseudo-column based on whether the immediately preceding record is more than one day behind the current record.  Then, we can aggregate over each effective group, where group is defined as Col1, Col2, and the pseudo-column.
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT t.*, CASE WHEN Date_col - LAG(Date_col) OVER (
                                         PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, Quantity ORDER BY Date_col) > 1
                     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS seq
    FROM tab1 t
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT t.*, SUM(seq) OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, Quantity ORDER BY Date_col) AS grp
    FROM cte1 t
)

SELECT
     Col1,
     Col2,
     MIN(Date_col) AS Startdate,
     MAX(Date_col) AS Enddate,
     Quantity
FROM cte2
GROUP BY
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Quantity,
    grp
ORDER BY
    Col1,
    Col2,
    MIN(Date_col);


Thanks for the reply, however, it is not giving the desired output.  Some of the data is missing and getting wrongly aggregated to a different group.

I think my answer works for the sample data you provided.  You should highlight where my answer fails with your sample data.

Below is the output I am getting.
Col1 Col2    Startdate         Enddate           Quantity
I1  L1    01/Jul/2024    03/Jul/2024    10
I1  L1    12/Jul/2024   14/Jul/2024    10
I2  L2    05/Jul/2024   08/Jul/2024    26
I2  L2    10/Jul/2024   14/Jul/2024    34
I2  L2    21/Jul/2024   24/Jul/2024    20
10th to 14th record is incorrect. Instead, it should be split into 2 from 10th to 11th as 34 and 12th to 14th as 28.

Hmmm...are you saying that quantity also defines a group of records?

Yes. I am not able to paste the output properly. Sorry for that.

I have updated my answer...did you try it?

You can use math_recognize which give a more readable solution:
select col1, col2, start_date, end_date, quantity from tab1
match_recognize (
    partition by col1, col2, quantity
    order by Date_col
    measures first(Date_col) as start_date, last(Date_col) as end_date
    pattern( (grp | strt)+ )
    define
        grp as Date_col = next(Date_col)-1
)
order by col1, col2, start_date;

NB the strt pattern is need to get orphan lines -the ones unique in their group- in the output, but you may adapt by replacing by "grp+ strt" if you don't want them.

This does not give the expected answer fiddle as it merges the I1/L1 rows into a single group. It is because the pattern allows strt to be repeatedly matched; what you probably want is grp* strt (although strt is mis-named as it would be the final row of the match and not the start).

An alternative pre-12c version to what MT0 suggested is to use tabibitosan to generate a grouping column that you can then use in the aggregate query:
select col1,
       col2,
       quantity,
       min(date_col) start_date,
       max(date_col) end_date
from   (select col1,
               col2,
               date_col,
               quantity,
               date_col - row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, quantity order by date_col) grp
        from   tab1)
group by col1,
         col2,
         quantity,
         grp
order by col1,
         col2,
         grp;

This works by assigning a rowcount to our groups identified by the col1, col2 and quantity columns, then subtracting that from the date_col. If rows have consecutive dates, the difference will remain constant. Jumps in date will provide a bigger difference. Then we can use this value in the aggregation to find the min/max dates per subgroup.
Example db<>fiddle (piggybacked off MT0's)
